# bash and POSIX shell difference in dot command

Tags: bash, shell

I encountered an issue with sourcing a script.
If somebody knows what went wrong, share please.
When I run `script.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
. preparing_script.sh # contents: func1(){ echo 'It works!' ; }
func1
```

It prints nothing. But when I change script to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
. preparing_script.sh # contents: func1(){ echo 'It works!' ; }
func1
```

It prints "It works!".
Is it intended that original shell does not source functions?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: mystery, set command in script.sh does not show the function func1!?

Comment: What shell is `sh` in your system, what system is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`function` keyword before function definition is `bash`-ism, not defined by POSIX.

So when you are running it with `sh` (shebang `#!/bin/sh`), it's not working (will show a syntax error for `(`), but using `bash` (shebang `#!/bin/bash`) works expectedly.

Comment: In fact `function` comes from ksh.

Comment: In `ksh`, functions defined with and without the keyword behave slightly differently; in `bash`, it's just decorative. (I assume `bash` adopted it partly to make it easier to port `ksh` code, partly for readability.)

Comment: the key word "function" was not the issue and it is missing in the original script on my disk. function keyword was intended to make things clear in this post which is about dot command (posix source).

Comment: sorry, it also works what i typed in the post. i probably have missed something in adaptation. but it was #!/bin/sh - #!/bin/bash difference definitely.

Comment: @user3694243 Does making `. ./preparing_script.sh` work?

Comment: no and the question is irrelevant right now. i don't know what i did by i solved my problem, there was something with variables scope. however the issue with #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash remains.